# Representing a cooking recipe in a graph database

Tags: data-modeling, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to wrap my head around graph databases.  So maybe someone could help explain to me the right way to model this relationship.  This is mostly from the perspective of neo4j, but I assume it would be applicable to most graph databases

I have a `Recipe` node and `Ingredient` nodes.  The `Ingredient` nodes have a `ingredient_in` relationship to the `Recipe` node.  The relationship will hold several attributes, of particular note is an amount field with a unit of measure.

I can imagine that elsewhere in the graph there would be a `UnitOfMeasure` nodes that would have converts_to relationships with a conversion ratio.

The point I'm struggling with is how do I represent the Ingredient->Recipe relationship as having a UnitOfMeasure.  Coming from RDMS this feels like I need a another node in between, but that feels wrong for a graph database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on two things:

a) do you have attributed relations or n-ary relations

b) how do you use the units and amounts - possibly a node in between is easier

Imo, using a "normal" design like this

```
Recipe -- Entry          -- Ingredient
          amount: double
             |
             |
          UniOfMeasure
```

is fine with Entry being a Node - even if you use a graph database which can handle attributed edges. The design would be quite the same with an attributed n-ary edge btw - the only difference would be that Entry, now possibly named "contains", would be an Edge not a Node.